# TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableView.setModel' called with wrong argument types

Tags: python, pyqt5, model-view, qsqltablemodel

here's my starting position:

1. I've created an interface file using QtDesigner.
2. In the interface file I have a model-based QTableView.
3. I'm trying to build a model for that view, following the structure of the official PyQt documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#details
   The model will be accessing a database.
4. Am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:******\main.py", line> 89, in 
> window = MainWindow()
>
> File "D:******\main.py", line 28, in **init**
> self.set_individual_clients_model()
>
> File "D:******\main.py", line 48, in set_individual_clients_model
> self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
>
> TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableView.setModel' called with wrong argument types:
> PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableView.setModel(QSqlTableModel)
>
> Supported signatures:
> PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableView.setModel(PySide2.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel)

When I try to run, I get the above error.

Here's my code:

```
from ui_interface import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlTableModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QMessageBox


settings = QSettings()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()

        loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)

        self.show()

        QAppSettings.updateAppSettings(self)

        self.set_individual_clients_model()

    # INDIVIDUAL CLIENTS PAGE
    def set_individual_clients_model(self):

        # set up the model
        self.model.setTable("ind_clients")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        self.model.select()
        self.model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
        self.model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "First Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Last Name")
        self.model.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Date of Birth")
        self.model.setHeaderData(4, Qt.Horizontal, "Doc Number")
        self.model.setHeaderData(5, Qt.Horizontal, "Doc Type")
        self.model.setHeaderData(6, Qt.Horizontal, "Doc Text")
        self.model.setHeaderData(7, Qt.Horizontal, "Country")

        # set the view
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.ui.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.ui.tableView.view()

        return


def create_connection():
    conn = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
    conn.setDatabaseName("alaric")
    user = os.environ.get("DB_USER")
    password = os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD")
    if not conn.open(user, password):
        QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            "Database Error!",
            "Database Error: %s" % conn.lastError().databaseText()
        )
        return False

    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    create_connection()

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any help with in successfully connecting the view and the model would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using PySide-5.15.7 with Qt 5.15.7 on Linux: `from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtSql; QtWidgets.QTableView().setModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel())`. If that raises an exception on your system, there must be a bug in the version of PySide2 you are using.

Comment: @ekhumoro Looking at your test scenario, I realised that in my interface file PySide2 is used, while in my main file I'm using PyQt5.QtSql.QSqlTableModel. Switching the import statement to PySide2.QtSqlTableModel solved my issue. Thanks a lot for looking into this.